# How to send extra parameters in jaxl xmpp ejabberd?

Tags: php, xmpp, ejabberd, jaxl

I want to send some extra parameters to xmpp server. but not getting those extra parameters in msg.
using  https://github.com/jaxl/JAXL  , https://www.ejabberd.im/

I'm trying with this method which is inside jaxl.php.

```
public function send_msg($to,$body,$sender_id,$id,$xmpp_msg_attribute,$thread=null, $subject=null) {
    $msg = new XMPPMsg(
        array(
            'id'=>$id,
            'sender_id'=>$sender_id,
            'type'=>'normal', 
            'to'=>$to, 
            'from'=>$this->full_jid->to_string(),
            'attributes'=> 'extra information',
        ), 
        $body,
        $thread,
        $subject
    );
    $this->send($msg);
}
```

but output sending without extra parameters:

```
<message xml:lang='en'
         to='7070707070@localhost.com'
         from='9696969696@localhost.com/jaxl#3090b93066351b9a90ebad79bb208745'
         id='5b6137010b0bc'
         xmlns='jabber:client'>
  <body><p>check me</p></body>
</message>
```

I didn't found attributes , sender_id .
i also tried changing attributes -> attrs.

source
http://jaxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/xml_objects.html#xmppstanza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Message and Body elements are already defined by XMPP protocols, so you can't add attributes to them.

But you can add new elements, for example a client can send this, and will be received by the destination:

```
<message id='46:941386'
    xml:lang='es'
    type='chat'
    to='user2@localhost'>
  <body>hola</body>
  <xxx aa='asd' bb='qwe'/>
</message>
```

Comment: how you made this? <xxx aa='asd' bb='qwe'/>, i know $msg->c('message_extra');
  $msg->t($xmpp_msg_attribute); but attribute aa and bb hows that? give example

Comment: I don't use JAXL, so I don't know how to do it in that library.